# Search multiple git repositories at once for unstaged changes

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Can not update zsh due to git unstaged changes but I don't know which repo the unstaged changes are in. Is there a way to check multiple repo directories at once for unstaged changes or do I literally have to go into each repo and check status?

When I try to run `upgrade_oh_my_zsh`, I get this output:

```
$ upgrade_oh_my_zsh
Upgrading Oh My Zsh
error: Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
There was an error updating. Try again later?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh My Zsh is installed by default to `~/.oh-my-zsh` using `git clone`, so that's the directory with unstaged commits when you try to upgrade. If you don't have any changes in there you want to keep, this is the easiest way to fix it:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh
git checkout .
```

Then you can run `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` again.

If you've been editing things you want to keep, run `git status` inside `~/.oh-my-zsh` to see what's around, then commit or clean out the parts you want.

Comment: Brilliant! That was it apparently when you modify your .gitignore it causes the error but your solution worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have several tools which can manage multiple repositories at once.

- http://myrepos.branchable.com/
- http://mixu.net/gr/

And the one im recommanding on is this one:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/mr

---

Basically you have 2 options:

1. Use a script which search for any folder with `.git` inside and check the status
2. Use a tool to manage all the repos.